# AmbiguousViewMatcherException Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, exoplayer

I am trying to write an Espresso Test using IdlingResource to check for video playback.

My project is hosted [here](https://github.com/gautamhans1/BakeAid)

This is the test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class RecipeFetchTest {

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<RecipeActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(RecipeActivity.class);

private IdlingResource mIdlingResource;

@Before
public void registerIdlingResource() {
    mIdlingResource = mActivityTestRule.getActivity().getIdlingResource();
    Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
}


@Test
public void checkRecipeNameRecipeActivity() {
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.rv_recipes)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(1));
    onView(withText("Brownies")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}

@Test
public void checkPlayerViewIsVisibleRecipeDetailActivity1() {
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.rv_recipes)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0,click()));
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.rv_steps)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0,click()));
 withContentDescription("playerVideo"))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withId(R.id.playerView)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}


@After
public void unregisterIdlingResource() {
    if (mIdlingResource != null) {
        Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
    }
}

}
```

and I get test fail with this error:

```
android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: '(with id: 
gautamhans.xyz.bakeaid:id/playerView and is displayed on the screen to the 
user)' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.

+--------->SimpleExoPlayerView{id=2131558584, res-name=playerView, 
visibility=VISIBLE, width=871, height=399, has-focus=false, has-
focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, 
is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-
selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, 
x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3} ****MATCHES****

+---------->PlaybackControlView{id=2131558584, res-name=playerView, 
visibility=VISIBLE, width=871, height=399, has-focus=false, has-
focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, 
is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-
selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, 
x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1} ****MATCHES****
```

According to the test, I have two views with the same res-id i.e. "playerView".

One is **SimpleExoPlayerView**
and the other is **PlaybackControlView**

I remember defining **SimpleExoPlayerView** but not **PlaybackControlView** .

So, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue.

I think SimpleExoPlayer generate a PlaybackControlView automatically.
I didn't know if we can avoid this generation but I get a workaround.

Look this line :

```
onView(allOf(instanceOf(SimpleExoPlayerView.class), withId(R.id.playerView))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

I just add a Matcher to be sure to check the SimpleExoPlayer object and then I check if it's displayed correctly.